Async execution of stored procedure hangs
I have an Async method in Spring boot that executes stored procedure in Oracle
@Autowired
EntityManager entityManager;

@Async ("taskExecutor")
public CompletableFuture<ResultObject> executeProcedure(Arg arg1) {
ResultObject resultObject = null;
try{
   StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("PROCEDURE_NAME");
   storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
   storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter(2, ResultSet.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR);
   storedProcedure.setParameter(1, arg1);
   resultObject = storedProcedure.getResultList();
   log.info("Retrieved result for arg {}", arg1);
} catch (Exception e) {
 //exception handling
}
return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(resultObject);
}

In another class I have this called.
List<ResultObject> results = argList
.stream()
.map(arg -> serviceClass.executeProcedure(arg))
.map(CompletableFuture::join)
.toList();

Executor config looks something like this
    @Bean(name = "taskExecutor")
    public TaskExecutor adminTaskExecutor() {
        final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(20);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(50);
        executor.setKeepAliveSeconds(threadTtl);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("Task thread - ");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }

Stored procedure looks like this
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_delta_users (
    p_user_schema IN VARCHAR2,
    p_person_schema IN VARCHAR2,
    p_where_clause IN VARCHAR2,
    p_person_id IN NUMBER,
    p_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
IS
v_user_store_query VARCHAR2(4000);
v_role_membership_query VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN

v_user_store_query := ' SELECT username FROM ' || p_user_schema || '.users_view WHERE ';
v_person_store_query := ' SELECT username FROM ' || p_person_schema || '.person WHERE person_id = ' || p_person_id;

OPEN p_cursor FOR '(' || v_user_store_query || '(' || p_where_clause || ')' || ' MINUS ' || v_person_store_query || ')' || ' UNION ' || '(' || v_person_store_query || ' MINUS ' || v_user_store_query || '(' || p_where_clause || ')' || ')' ;

END;


Please ignore the args passed to procedure and what's shown in my sample code

I am facing issue when the arglist increases, thread execution simply hangs. All is well when the size is around 100, when arglist increases to 1000, threads seem to freeze around 930~950th task.
I have tried increasing Hikaripool size, executor pool size. No luck.
I've tried increasing the executor pool size. Initially was 5, increased to 20. Parallel execution became faster but still got when reaching the end of arglist.
I have also tried increasing Hikaripool size. initially was 20, increased to 100. Still did not see  any change in the behaviour.
Read somewhere that EntityManger is not thread safe. Tried creating entitymanager within each thread using EntityManagerFactory and destroying it finally. But ended up with the same issue.

I think your problem is in the stored procedure. Can you show its code?

@AndreySmelik I've added the stored procedure

@AndreySmelik your guess was right! I changed the procedure sql query to return count instead of actual result. That completed all thread executions!
Some threads are not able to complete because the result set was huge list of users. Need to figure out an efficient way to handle that! Thank you!
